I want to use nested loop in Julia
using JuMP, Gurobi
using DataFrames
using Plots
using Statistics
data = [
    66.6 66.1 68.5 72.1 71.6 73.7 73.5;
    63.3 63.8 66.0 69.6 69.0 70.7 70.6;
    61.4 62.3 64.1 68.0 67.1 69.0 68.5;
    59.7 61.9 63.6 67.3 66.5 68.3 67.5;
    60.1 63.3 65.0 68.4 68.1 69.5 67.8;
    60.7 67.2 68.9 72.2 72.3 73.6 69.4;
    62.7 74.0 75.8 79.1 79.5 80.8 72.8;
    64.7 79.7 83.0 84.2 84.5 85.5 74.0;
    65.9 78.9 85.1 83.3 83.1 81.6 69.5;
    66.1 77.1 86.4 80.8 79.8 73.1 62.4;
    66.1 72.8 84.3 75.7 76.0 65.5 55.7;
    64.3 68.1 80.3 71.1 73.4 58.7 49.8;
    64.7 63.8 72.3 68.6 70.1 55.0 45.9;
    64.0 60.8 67.7 67.5 66.8 53.2 44.4;
    63.7 60.8 71.4 68.0 63.9 52.4 43.9;
    64.2 61.6 76.0 69.2 64.8 53.2 46.2;
    65.6 63.8 79.4 71.5 67.6 57.4 50.7;
    70.0 70.5 82.1 76.4 72.1 64.9 59.4;
    73.7 77.0 84.6 81.2 79.8 74.9 70.1;
    78.7 82.8 88.1 86.2 87.3 83.1 78.2;
    78.5 82.6 87.1 86.2 87.6 84.4 79.9;
    77.0 80.5 84.5 84.0 85.6 83.1 79.0;
    73.0 76.2 79.8 79.4 81.3 80.1 76.4;
    68.7 71.2 74.6 74.8 76.5 76.1 73.1
]

Gmax = [20, 25, 25, 30, 20]
Cost = [12, 16, 18, 24, 36]

result_g = zeros(5, 4, 24)
result_c = zeros(1, 4, 24)

# for date in 1:7
date = 1
m = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)
@variable(m, g[i in 1:5, j in 1:24] >= 0)
@constraint(m, g_ub[i in 1:5, j in 1:24], g[i, j] <= Gmax[i])
@constraint(m, SDbalanced, [(a, b) in zip(1:5, 1:24), i in a], sum(g[i,j] for j in b)==data[j,i])
@objective(m, Min, sum(Cost[i] * g[i, j] for i in 1:5 for j in 1:24))

print(m)
optimize!(m)
termination_status(m)
objective_value(m)
value.(g)
global result_g[:, j] = value.(g)
global result_c[:, j] = [objective_value(m)]

# end

result_g
result_c

I am trying to use nested loop in julia to make a constraint to make generation(g[i,j]) to be same as the demand(data[j,i]). How can I fix the sdbalanced constraint?
ERROR: LoadError: At /Users/gimseong-won/KENTECH/2nd grade 1st sem/Introduction of smartgrid/DR_project/DemandTOU.jl:43: @constraint(m, SDbalanced, [(a, b) in zip(1:5, 1:24), i in a], sum((g[i, j] for j = b)) == data[j, i]): Unsupported constraint expression: we don't know how to parse constraints containing expressions of type :vect.

The @constraint macro has too many parameters. If this @constraint is meant to generate a collection of constraints, perhaps you can clarify which constraints should be generated.

The problematic constraint is:
@constraint(m, SDbalanced, [(a, b) in zip(1:5, 1:24), i in a], sum(g[i,j] for j in b)==data[j,i])

which, formatted differently, is:
@constraint(
    m,
    SDbalanced,
    [(a, b) in zip(1:5, 1:24), i in a],
    sum(g[i,j] for j in b)==data[j,i],
)

This is not valid JuMP syntax.
You probably mean instead:
@constraint(
    m,
    SDbalanced[(a, b) in zip(1:5, 1:24), i in a],
    sum(g[i,j] for j in b)==data[j,i],
)

but now the constraint doesn't make sense because j does not exist for data[j,i], and your zip is not doing what you think it is doing:
julia> [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(1:5, 1:24)]
5-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 1)
 (2, 2)
 (3, 3)
 (4, 4)
 (5, 5)

Do you mean instead something like:
@constraint(
    m,
    SDbalannced[i in 1:5],
    sum(g[i, :]) == sum(data[:, i]),
)

p.s., If you have follow-up questions, you can ask on https://jump.dev/forum
